# Why I am having trouble plotting the AUC?

Tags: python, matplotlib, auc, roc

I am trying to plot the roc_auc curve however I am not getting any results. Any explanation here? Are there any problems with the number of data?

Here is my example :

```
test_predictionLR_proba = [0.94300342, 0.85976558, 0.84546944, 0.61105814, 0.88627872,
       0.41703218, 0.47188134, 0.5981626 , 0.86871501, 0.83757875,
       0.85976558, 0.73893018, 0.64715939, 0.66325802, 0.94300342,
       0.6961341 , 0.94300342, 0.35931487, 0.15670699, 0.28703131,
       0.30787549, 0.14553577, 0.20970746, 0.75035318, 0.21261297,
       0.18141668, 0.23722738, 0.18923114, 0.33072182, 0.30913881,
       0.40672414, 0.25698922, 0.24362062, 0.42598312]

false_positive_rate = [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.05882353, 0.05882353, 0.11764706, 0.11764706, 1.        ]

true_positive_rate = [0.        , 0.17647059, 0.29411765, 0.41176471, 0.52941176,
       0.52941176, 0.94117647, 0.94117647, 1.        , 1.        ]

plt.plot(list(false_positive_rate), list(true_positive_rate), marker='.', label= 'ROC curve (area = %0.2f)' % roc_auc_score(Y_test, test_predictionLR_proba))
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `roc_auc_score` bit and ran this:

```
test_predictionLR_proba = [0.94300342, 0.85976558, 0.84546944, 0.61105814, 0.88627872,
       0.41703218, 0.47188134, 0.5981626 , 0.86871501, 0.83757875,
       0.85976558, 0.73893018, 0.64715939, 0.66325802, 0.94300342,
       0.6961341 , 0.94300342, 0.35931487, 0.15670699, 0.28703131,
       0.30787549, 0.14553577, 0.20970746, 0.75035318, 0.21261297,
       0.18141668, 0.23722738, 0.18923114, 0.33072182, 0.30913881,
       0.40672414, 0.25698922, 0.24362062, 0.42598312]

false_positive_rate = [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.05882353, 0.05882353, 0.11764706, 0.11764706, 1.        ]

true_positive_rate = [0.        , 0.17647059, 0.29411765, 0.41176471, 0.52941176,
       0.52941176, 0.94117647, 0.94117647, 1.        , 1.        ]

plt.plot(list(false_positive_rate), list(true_positive_rate), marker='.', label= 'ROC curve (area = %0.2f)')
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.show()
```

Seemed to work fine, what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting "ValueError: continuous format is not supported". Try to round of  your Y_test values to single digit and run it and I have changed the code little bit.

I have assumed y_test1 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve

test_predictionLR_proba = np.asarray([0.94300342, 0.85976558, 0.84546944, 0.61105814, 0.88627872,
       0.41703218, 0.47188134, 0.5981626 , 0.86871501, 0.83757875,
       0.85976558, 0.73893018, 0.64715939, 0.66325802, 0.94300342,
       0.6961341 , 0.94300342, 0.35931487, 0.15670699, 0.28703131,
       0.30787549, 0.14553577, 0.20970746, 0.75035318, 0.21261297,
       0.18141668, 0.23722738, 0.18923114, 0.33072182, 0.30913881,
       0.40672414, 0.25698922, 0.24362062, 0.42598312])
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test1,test_predictionLR_proba)
plt.plot(fpr, label = 'fpr')
plt.plot(tpr, label = 'tpr')
plt.legend(fontsize=16)
```